# Updating a Power Query automatically when adding rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

Whenever I add some rows to my query, the left side of my workbook doesn't update. I have to manually update it each time.

Is there a way to get it to update automatically?

[image]

Comment: Power Query creates Workbook connections that can also be refreshed on open. You can find the relevant Power Query-generated connections in the Workbook Connections dialog under ,,,,

`Data , Connections, and configure the settings`. Or I can suggest you VBA (Macro) solution also to refresh the connections. ☺

Comment: You can use the sortcut key: Ctrl+Shift+F5 after adding or modifying data source.